# How to display FullCalendar.io events horizontally as icons, retaining responsiveness? (codepen provided)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to show the events of FullCalendar (fullcalendar.io) horizontally as icons, rather than as text.

I was able to replace the text by an icon using the eventRender function. (see codepen)

But I can't seem to find anywhere how to display them horizontally, while keeping responsiveness and not changing the core code. Ideally they would behave like separate left floated elements.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/JM007/pen/rjdybv

[The way I would like to display them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOfbS.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    displayEventTime: false,
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    allDayDefault: false,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,

    eventRender: function(event, el) {

      el.find('.fc-content').html("<i class='fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x'></i>");

    },
    events: [{
      id:1,
      title: 'event1',
      start: '2017-01-01 06:44:00'
    }, {
      id:2,
      title: 'event2',
      start: '2017-01-01 06:50:00',
    }, {
      id:3,
      title: 'event3',
      start: '2017-02-01 10:50:00',
    }, {
      id:4,
      title: 'event3',
      start: '2017-02-01 12:50:00',
    }, {
      id:5,
      title: 'event3',
      start: '2017-02-01 13:50:00',
    }, ]
  })

});
```

```html
<html>
  
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
</head>
  
 <body>
   <div id='calendar'></div>
 </body>
  
 </html>
```

Comment: I Don't think it is possible without changing a markup since these are tables

Comment: they are all on different table rows...you would need to reconstruct those rows after rendering all events